# How to anticipate the width of a span based on a string using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**edit 1** : the width seems to depend on a lot of parameters. but i don't need a perfect width, even if the width is wider than the longest word, it is ok as I will text-align center to enhance visibility.

---

I have a javascript framework that builds a dictionary of translated words.
Hence I got a json from the server of the form :

```
[
 {"word":"house", "translation":"maison"},
 {"word":"dog", "translation":"chien"},
 ...
]
```

and the list is build as followed :

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="i in list">
      <span class="word">{{ i.word }}</span>
      <span class="translation">{{ i.translation }}</span>
  </li>
...
</ul>
```

both the `span` are going to be :

```
span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

and the `li` needs to be of the width of the longest word between `word` and `translation`.

in my script when receiving the json, i need then to perform the calculation as to save the width of the li, so i can write

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="i in list" style="width:{{ i.width }}">...</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

My question is how can I calculate the width of a span based on a string. which css properties my calculation needs to include ?

**note** : even I use angular, i am not bound to use only angular directives, i can use pure javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a dummy span and get its width something like this:

```
var span = angular.element('<span>')
.css({ position: 'absolute', left: '-5000px', display: 'block' });
var widest = 0;
angular.forEach(array, function (item) {
    angular.element('body').append(span.html(item.word));
    if (span.width() > widest) {
        widest = span.width() ;
    }
    //'angular.element' or '$' if there is jQuery in the page
    angular.element('body').append(span.html(item.translation));
    if (span.width() > widest) {
        widest = span.width() ;
    }
    span.remove();
});
```

This is not tested but it should work.

Comment: i like the trick, however i wish my problem could be resolved with just string and calculations

Comment: @발렌텐 This is the only way if you want it to be accurate. If you want to know what width the browser will give, ask the browser itself.

Comment: at first I thought that was a jQuery directive but it seems like i can use $ without it, is that part of angular ?

Comment: @발렌텐 You can add the above code in the directive where the list is. If you have jQuery in the page, you can replace `angular.element` with `$`, but it's the same thing.